# C and Python - communicating with sockets

Tags: python, c, sockets, unix, dns

I'm trying to use UNIX domain sockets to communicate between a C program, and a Python script. The Python script sends data via UNIX domain sockets to the C program.

Here is the relevant code from my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>    
#define UNIX_PATH_MAX 100

int main(void)
{
struct sockaddr_un address;
int socket_fd, connection_fd;
socklen_t address_length;
pid_t child;

socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (socket_fd < 0){
    printf("socket() failed\n");
    return 1;
} 

unlink("/tmp/demo_socket");
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));

address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, "/tmp/demo_socket");

if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) != 0) {
    printf("bind() failed\n");
    return 1;
}
if(listen(socket_fd, 5) != 0) {
    printf("listen() failed\n");
    return 1;
}

//----------------WHILE LOOP----------------------->
while((connection_fd = accept(socket_fd, 
                            (struct sockaddr *) &address,
                            &address_length)) > -1)
{
.
.
.(doesn't get any further than this)
```

This is the python script I am using to send a message to the socket:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect("/tmp/demo_socket")
print "Sending..."
s.send("Hello world")
x = s.recv(1024)
print x
s.close()
```

The python script fails with the error "Broken Pipe". The C program never enters the while loop because the accept() function fails and returns '-1'.

Why is accept() failing? And what can I do to make it succeed?

Comment: Print out `errno` (or better: `strerror(errno)`) in your C code when accept fails. That and the man page should tell you at least part of the answer.

Comment: It fails on the error "Invalid Argument".

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [an example I found](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html), it seems that the length you pass `bind` should not count the terminating or padding nulls in the `sockaddr_un`.

Try:

```
size_t addrlen;
const char* sockname = "/tmp/demo_socket";

/* ... */

address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
snprintf(address.sun_path, UNIX_PATH_MAX, sockname);
addrlen = sizeof(address.sun_family) + strlen(sockname);

if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, addrlen) != 0) {
    printf("bind() failed\n");
    return 1;
}
```

P.S. Because of this, you don't need the `memset` call.

Comment: Hi @mike the link seems to be broken... can u kindly fix it ?

Comment: It might simply be gone at this point. I’m keeping the link there because it’s not my original work, but it’s been so long I’m not sure I can find a better link. In any case the link isn’t needed for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, `address_length` needs to be initialized to the size of `sockaddr_un` before the `accept()` call.  During the call, it is loaded with the actual length of the peer address that is shoved into `address`.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: Brilliant! After reading your tip, and a little googling, I came up with a solution by setting: address_length = sizeof(address); before my accept() call. Thanks!